# UDP broadcast for IoT discovery using Raspberry PI and public wifi

Tags: raspberry-pi, udp, wifi, iot, broadcast

A couple questions.

1. TLDR is sending UDP broadcast packets on a Wifi network to allow for discovery of a IoT device (Raspberry PI) a conventional practice?

Long version:  I'm working on an IoT project for a class.  Based on other IoT devices I've used (a Christmas carol lighting system and music player), we decided to utilize an already working application (https://github.com/balena-os/wifi-connect).  The way it works is it runs on the Raspberry PI and hosts a wifi endpoint through the RPI's network card that the user can connect to. Once a user connects to this Wifi endpoint on his/her Iphone, a Wifi selection and password entry page appears on his/her Iphone.  The user enters the Wifi/password that the IoT device (Raspberry PI) should connect to.  The entered Wifi will then be connected to by the Raspberry PI.  The user can then connect to the entered Wifi as well and now both the user's Iphone and Raspberry PI will be connected to the same Wifi network.

We decided to send UDP packets to the broadcast address of the Wifi network from the IoT device, so that users connected to the Wifi (via their Iphones) can "discover" the IoT devices IP address by listening for UDP packets.  Once the user discovers the IoT device's IP address, they can send HTTP RESTful API calls to the IoT device.  I was wondering if the described process is conventionally used.

```
# script we are using to send UDP broadcast packets
import socket
import time

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

server.settimeout(0.2)
message = b"message"
while True:
    server.sendto(message, ('<broadcast>', 16123))
    time.sleep(1)
```

2. We tried this setup at a public library, using their free public wifi.  However, the UDP broadcast packet discovery process failed.  UDP broadcast packets were sent out by the IoT device, but were not received by the Iphone.  We're wondering if this has something to do with a firewall.  We could successfully send UDP broadcast packets from a Macbook (via a python script) to an IOS emulator residing on the same Macbook, such that the source IP address of the packet was the same as the recipient.  Is there a firewall rule such that a broadcast packet sent from IP address [A] can be delivered back to IP address [A] but not to IP address [B].

Also, I didn't mess around with the port number, which might have helped if certain ports were disabled by a firewall.  I'm not sure. Help is appreciated.  We are both relatively new to this.

Answer (score 1):

DNS-SD ([RFC6763](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6763)) is the a fairly common and standardized way to do network discovery. It actually supports both TCP & UDP services. It was originally invented by Apple under the brand name "Bonjour" for printer discovery.

So yes, it is common to use UDP broadcast packets (via DNS-SD) for IoT device discovery on a Wifi network.